# Solana cli 1.18.0 warnings

Tags: solana-cli

I am running into this warning on Solana cli 1.18.0:

warning: use of deprecated function `solana_program::borsh0_10::get_instance_packed_len`: Please upgrade to Borsh 1.X and use `borsh1::get_instance_packed_len` instead

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like this is just a warning. Does this prevent you from building?

Comment: The warning message is supposed to be helpful: it says to upgrade to using `borsh` v1 in your project and use `solana_program::borsh1` instead of `solana_program::borsh0_10`. Is there some way to make it clearer?

Comment: Gm Jon and Jonas! Thanks for your answers! How do I enforce solana_program::borsh1?
It seems that this is used by default, so how do I change it?